# C# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005)

Tags: c#, winforms, phpmyadmin

here's my connection string

```
"Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.x;Database=database;Uid='root';Pwd='';"
```

the ip on the server is the ip of the other computer(have xampp) that I want to access.

this is the Exception I receive.

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect
>   to any of the specified MySQL hosts.    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()

Comment: First Please dont post your credentials here. Second: your `password` is `""` or `";"`

Comment: ok sorry.. my password is empty.

Comment: You have to allow remote access to user

Comment: How to allow the user?

Answer (score 1):

With mysql on C# you don't need single quote in the connexion string

Ex :

```
ConnStr = "Server = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX; Database = mydatabase; Uid = root; Pwd = yourpassword";   

MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr)
```

You can also verify that you can ping the other computer :

```
    using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

    public static bool IsConnectedToServer()
    {
        Ping p = new Ping();
        try
        {
            PingReply reply = p.Send("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 3000);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your connection string is wrong

I should be In `<appSettings>` in

```
<add key="myConnectionString" value="Server=localhost;Database=dbName;User Id=username;Password=password;"/>
```

or

in `<connectionStrings>`

```
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Server=Server=localhost;Database=dbName;User Id=username;Password=password;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

As well as Refer this [Link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) to Enable Remote Access for Mysql

Comment: I think my connection string is correct. because when I'm accessing the database from pc1 to pc1Database I can access it without problem. using the server=localhost. but when I'm trying to access the database on pc2. using the IP. I'm receiving the error I mention on the top.