# Error in C# MySQL Query?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

I'm receiving an unexpected error on my MySQL query, can anyone help me discover why?

Error message:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON users.id =
>   user_auth_tickets.user_id WHERE user_auth_tickets.auth_ticket = 'N' at
>   line 1

Query:

```
dbConnection.SetQuery("SELECT users.id,users.username,users.rank,users.motto,users.look,users.gender,users.last_online,users.credits,users.activity_points,users.home_room,users.block_newfriends,users.hide_online,users.hide_inroom,users.vip,users.account_created,users.vip_points,users.machine_id,users.volume,users.chat_preference,users.focus_preference,users.pets_muted,users.bots_muted,users.advertising_report_blocked,users.last_change,users.gotw_points,users.ignore_invites,users.time_muted,users.allow_gifts,users.friend_bar_state,users.disable_forced_effects,users.allow_mimic,users.rank_vip " +
  "FROM users" +
  "JOIN user_auth_tickets " +
  "ON users.id = user_auth_tickets.user_id " +
  "WHERE user_auth_tickets.auth_ticket = @sso AND last_ip = @lastIp " +
  "LIMIT 1"
);
```

Comment: I wonder how many of these questions there are already here... If you are going to concatenate strings so horribly, at least check the resulting string using a debugger

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto more than we are going to ever bother counting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665251/c-sharp-mysql-data-mysqlclient-mysqlexception-0x80004005)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You could at least [mark the answer that helped you as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to repay the effort that the person did to help you. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in MySQL Query in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413561/error-in-mysql-query-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

There is no space in the `"From users"+"JOIN ..."`

So its read

`Select <stuff> from usersJOIN user_auth_tickets on` ..